# My two js functions that work seperately but not together

Tags: javascript, function, button

So I have tried to create a function that clears the screen and sends me an alert based on what button I have pressed. I can clear the screen without any problems and also receive the alert but I can't seem to make both happen with one press of a button.

```
<head>
<script>
    function cleartext() {
        document.getElementById("text0").style.display = "none";
    }   

    function btnchecklist() {
        document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {
            alert("hello1");
        }
        document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {
            alert("hello2");
        }
        document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function() {
            alert("hello3");
        }
    }       
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="text0"> 
        <p> some text </p>
    </div>     

    <div id="btn-group">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="cleartext(); btnchecklist();"> 1 </button>
        <button id="btn2" onclick="cleartext(); btnchecklist();"> 2 </button>
        <button id="btn3" onclick="cleartext(); btnchecklist();"> 3 </button>    
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use a comma, use a normal semi-colon... `onclick="cleartext();btnchecklist();"`

Comment: Note that you're rebinding the buttons on every click, but the alert will not ever happen on the first click. It will happen on every subsequent click.

Comment: ...and after the first click, `alert()` will be attached, but `cleartext()` will be gone.

Comment: Is it possible to attach the two to a single button? I want both to happen with one press of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer below
PS. this is not the best solution if you explained to me what you want to do exactly may be I provide a cleaner answer.

```html
So I have tried to create a function that clears the screen and sends me an alert based on what button I have pressed. I
can clear the screen without any problems and also receive the alert but I can't seem to make both happen with one press
of a button.

<head>
  <script>
    function cleartext() {
      document.getElementById("text0").style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onload = function () {
      document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
        alert("hello1");
        cleartext();
      }
      document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function () {
        alert("hello2");
        cleartext();
      }
      document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function () {
        alert("hello3");
        cleartext();
      }
    };  
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="text0">
    <p> some text </p>
  </div>

  <div id="btn-group">
    <button id="btn1"> 1 </button>
    <button id="btn2"> 2 </button>
    <button id="btn3"> 3 </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use this code.

Pass the button element to your btnchecklist function (this) and in your function get the id of your passed element and show alert with the accordingly text.

```js
function cleartext() {
    document.getElementById("text0").style.display = "none";
  }

  function btnchecklist(element) {
    //Read id of element
    switch (el.id) {
      case "btn1":
        alert("hello1"); //Output in case of element id is btn1
        break;
      case "btn2":
        alert("hello2");
        break;
      case "btn3":
        alert("hello3");
        break;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="text0">
  <p> some text </p>
</div>

<div id="btn-group">
<!-- Pass element to your btnchecklist function (this) -->
  <button id="btn1" onclick="cleartext();btnchecklist(this)"> 1 </button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="cleartext();btnchecklist(this)"> 2 </button>
  <button id="btn3" onclick="cleartext();btnchecklist(this)"> 3 </button>
</div>
```

A shorter but more complicated code is:

```
  var aButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#btn-group>button"); //Get all buttons in btn-group
    aButtons.forEach(function(oButton){ //Loop buttons
    oButton.addEventListener("click", function(el){ //Add click event listener to each button
        var regex = new RegExp(/([\d+])/); //Regulr Expression to find the number in your bvutton id
      document.getElementById("text0").style.display = "none";
      alert("hello" + el.target.id.match(regex)[0]); //Alert "hello" Text + number in your button id
    });
  });
```

Comment: I can't seem to make this work either. I am using mz btw in case that has something to do with it.